# Compare two different tables with same rows but not exactly in the same order in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I want to compare two different tables in Excel if they have exactly the same rows [number of rows and their fields] but the rows may not be necessarilly in the same order,
say:

```
col1---col2---col3---col4                  col1---col2---col3---col4
1      10     15      2                    3      30     13     6
2      20     14      4                    4      40     12     8
3      30     13      6                    1      10     15     2
4      40     12      8                    2      20     14     4

         TABLE_1                                    TABLE_2
```

I call this equivalent tables.

Is there an excel function, or combination of functions, that can give me TRUE if both tables are equivalent, and FALSE if not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put two helper columns in the tables with the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:D2=INDEX(G:J,MATCH(A2,G:G,0),0)))=COLUMNS(A:D)
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(G2:J2=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(G2,A:A,0),0)))=COLUMNS(G:J)
```

[image]

Then count those helper columns for FALSE:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(E:E,FALSE)=0,COUNTIF(K:K,FALSE)=0)
```

This will return `FALSE` if any of the rows return false.

[image]

---

And when one cell does not match:

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you so much, was of much help, but in my real case, 
I have columns with CHAR values, will this still work??

Comment: yes, there is nothing in the formula that would make it dependent on numbers or characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may go around it with the following shortcut, which is not 100% sure but very high possibility of being sure. but it is extremely easy to apply.

first, format your tables as real Tables. Home enu>Format as Table
then, write this formula: =SUM(Table1)=SUM(Table2)
it would be very little probability for them to be equal if they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks ExcelinEfendisi, but I need to be as precise as possible, and, also, in real cases, I handle CHAR values.

Comment: then just add COUNT and AVERAGE as well, like "=(SUM(Table1)+COUNT(Table1)+AVERAGE(Table1))=(SUM(Table2)+COUNT(Table2)+AVERAGE(Table2))" . This will make it more precise :)